# check box backgroung change on checked

Tags: css

```
<span class="heading-filter">
    Cashback 
    <input class="cashback_check" value="1" type="checkbox">
    <label class="label-text"></label>
</span>
```

I need color change of checkbox and span also.

Comment: Have you got jQuery, or pure javascript only ?

Answer (score 0):

```
span.heading-filter{position:relative;}
input[type="checkbox"].cashback_check:checked + .label_txt::after {
content: "";
font-family: "FontAwesome";
left: 99px;
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
}
.heading-filter::after {
border: 1px solid;
content: "";
display: inline-block;
height: 18px;
width: 18px;
}
input.cashback_check{opacity:0;z-index:3;position:absolute;top:6px;left: 10px;height:30px; width:90%;}
```

```css
span.heading-filter{position:relative;}
 input[type="checkbox"].cashback_check:checked + .label-text::after {
 content: "ok";
 font-family: "FontAwesome";
 left:72px;
 position: absolute;
  color:red;
   top: 0px;
 }
 .heading-filter::after {
 border: 1px solid #000;
 content: "";
 display: inline-block;
 height: 18px;
 width: 18px;
 }
 input.cashback_check{opacity:0;z-index:3;position:absolute;top:0px;left: 10px;height:30px; width:90%;}
  input[type="checkbox"].cashback_check:checked span{background:#ccc;display:block}
```

```html
 <span class="heading-filter">Cashback <input class="cashback_check" value="1" type="checkbox"><label class="label-text"></label></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I make custom checkbox with css only please check.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  height: 15px;
  left: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 15px;
  right:0;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  background: #ccc;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
  color:orange;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  padding-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
}
span.heading-filter {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<span class="heading-filter"> <input id="check" class="cashback_check" 
value="1" type="checkbox"><label for="check" class="label-text">Cashback</label></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will add a background when checked, and remove it when uncheck your checkbox. Try it!

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '.cashback_check', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).closest('span').addClass('checked');
        $(this).addClass('checked');
    }
    else {
  $(this).closest('span').removeClass('checked');
        $(this).removeClass('checked');
    }
});
```

```css
.checked {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="heading-filter">
    Cashback 
    <input class="cashback_check" value="1" type="checkbox">
    <label class="label-text"></label>
</span>
```

My fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/eqomzkg5/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.heading-filter .label-text::before {
  background:#16a085;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  left: 134px;
  position: absolute;
  top:3px;
  width: 20px;
}
.heading-filter .label-text{display:block;padding:4px;font-weight:normal;}
input[type="checkbox"].cashback_check:checked + .label-text{background: #428bca none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;width:100%;}
span.heading-filter{position:relative;}
input[type="checkbox"].cashback_check:checked + .label-text::after {
    content: "";
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    left: 136px;
    position: absolute;top:3px;font-size:16px;
 
}
input[type="checkbox"].cashback_check:checked .heading-filter .label-text::before{background:#16a085}
.cashback_check {
  height: 30px;
  left: 124px;
  position:absolute;
  
  z-index: 2;display:block;width:30px;opacity:0;
  }
```

```html
<span class="heading-filter"><input class="cashback_check" value="1" type="checkbox"><label class="label-text">Cashback </label></span>
```

Comment: thanks for solutions but need text and after checkbox with color change. I solved it